# Wordpress with Laravel running on subfolder

Tags: wordpress, apache, laravel, .htaccess

I need to add a new Laravel app to an existing Wordpress website. Both will run via Apache webserver. The idea is that:

- `https://website.com/` -> Wordpress website
- `https://website.com/laravelapp` -> Laravel web application

In the filesystem, the root folder contains the Wordpress files and a subfolder `laravelapp` contains the Laravel files (so, the laravel `public` folder is a subfolder of `laravelapp`).

When I browse these, this is the current returned result:

- `https://website.com/` -> returns the Wordpress website, with working permalinks
- `https://website.com/laravelapp` -> returns 403 error
- `https://website.com/laravelapp/public` -> returns Laravel App

This shows me that mod_rewrite is available and working. But I want users to be able to just use the `https://website.com/laravelapp` to access that laravel app (not the public folder).

I've been trying to setup the `.htaccess` to make this arrangement possible, but am getting stuck. I currently have:

- `.htaccess` on root of website

  ```
  # BEGIN WordPress
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/laravelapp [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
  </IfModule>
  # END WordPress
  ```
- `.htaccess` on `laravelapp` folder

  ````
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /laravelapp/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
  </IfModule>
  ```
  ````
- `.htaccess` on `laravelapp/public` folder contains the standard laravel .htaccess file from the distributed package.

Is there any way to make this possible?

Comment: Is setting up your laravel application on a subdomain an option?

Comment: Unfortunately subdomain is not an option :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel site reading have

`RewriteBase /`

So the best way I think you need create one sub-domain for Laravel site.

But you still can try configure your .htaccess follow this:

1. Create a class to point to new location

Create a new file shared_hosting_root\applications\your_app_root\app\GoPublic.php

```
class GoPublic extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
{
    /**
    * Get the path to the public / web directory.
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function publicPath()
    {
    return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'../../public_html/your_app_name';
    }
}
```

We’re using relative path here so you don’t have to know the absolute path. But it is extremely crucial to follow the same recommended folder structure I’ve mentioned earlier.

You may need to run the following command in your root folder to autoload the new class. Otherwise you will get an error saying the class cannot be found.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

2. Edit bootstrap\app.php

   ```
   /* -- remove/comment this original code
   $app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
   );
   -- until here */

   /* -- add this new code -- */
   $app = new App\GoPublic(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
   );
   ```
3. Edit public\index.php

Change

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

To

```
require __DIR__.'/../../applications/your_app_name/bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Change

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

To

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../applications/your_app_name/bootstrap/app.php';
```

4. Copy public to public_html

Now, copy the content inside `applications\your_app_name\public into public_html\your_app_name`.

To simplify the process, I would create a bash file to automatically copy the files to the new location.

Create a new file `shared_hosting_root\applications\your_app_name\deploy.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Copy public folder to public_html/your_app_name"
rsync -rv ./public/ ../../public_html/your_app_name
```

Using rsync ensures that if you ever run this deploy.sh several times, only those that are newer will be copied to the new location.

When you’re ready to run it, in the terminal run:

```
?> cd applications\your_app_name
?> sh deploy.sh
```

Caution: You have to run deploy.sh within applications\your_app_name, otherwise it will fail.

5. Configure your `.htaccess`

Change your `.htaccess` follow this

```
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 

# Change example.com to your domain name
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 

# Change your_app_name to the subfolder name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/your_app_name/ 

# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# Change your_app_name to the subfolder name
# Change example.com to your domain name
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /your_app_name/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ your_app_name/index.php [L]
```

Hope this help!